# Searching and Reading a text file

Tags: c, scanf

this is my first time asking a question on here so I'll try to do my best. I'm not that great at C, I'm only in Intermediate C programming.

I'm trying to write a program that reads a file, which I got working. But I'm have search for a word then save the word after it into an array. What I have going right now is

```
for(x=0;x<=256;x++){
 fscanf(file,"input %s",insouts[x][0]);
 }
```

In the file there are lines that say "input A0;" and I want it to save "A0" to insouts[x][0]. 256 is just a number I picked because I don't know how many inputs it might have in the text file.

I have insouts declared as:

```
char * insouts[256][2];
```

Comment: What's the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: it won't save the "A0" to the array or atleast thats what I get that it's doing when I try to print it out. I just gives out a bunch of odd characters

Comment: Check the return value from `fscanf()`. For your format, it will return 1 when it is successful, and 0 or -1 otherwise. The data must consist of alternating `input` and `value` (where the values can change spelling but the inputs can't). There must be spaces between them.  I'd put a blank at the start of the format string to skip leading white space (`" input %s"`).  If your data isn't formatted like that, you probably need to use `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` in place of `fscanf()`.  I wish `fscanf()` was easier to use, and hence easier to teach; it is a minefield full or traps for novices.

Comment: You aren't allocating enough space of the correct type. You need a 2D array of `char` (not `char *`), and you need to allow for the null at the end of the string too.  So, `char insouts[256][3];` and `" input %2s"` for the format string, if the 'word' after 'input' is 1 or 2 characters only.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I had enough reputation to up vote your answer. I'm assuming the input names will be larger or maybe smaller than what was given in the test problem. So the %2s might not work :(. How would I go about using the  fgets and sscanf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fgets()` & `sscanf()`.  Seperate I/O from format scanning.

```
#define N (256)
char insouts[N][2+1]; // note: no  * and 2nd dimension is 3
for(size_t x = 0; x < N; x++){
   char buf[100];
   if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
     break;  // I/O error or EOF
   }
   int n = 0;
   //  2 this is the max length of characters for insouts[x].  A \0 is appended.
   //  [A-Za-z0-9]  this is the set of legitimate characters for insouts
   // %n record the offset of the scanning up to that point.
   int result = sscanf(buf, "input %2[A-Za-z0-9]; %n", insouts[x], &n);
   if ((result != 1) || (buf[n] != '\0')) {
      ; // format error
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the address of the x'th element of the array and not the value stored there. You can use the address-of operator `&` to do this.

I think

```
 for(x = 0;x < 256; x++){
     fscanf(file,"input %s", &insouts[x][0]); 
     // you could use insouts[x], which should be equivalent to &insouts[x][0]
 }
```

would do the trick :)

Also, you are only allocating 2 bytes for every string. Keep in mind that strings need to be terminated by a null character, so you should change the array allocation to

```
char * insouts[256][3];
```

However, I'm pretty sure the %s will match `A0;` and not just `A0`, so you might need to account for this as well. You can use %c together with a width to read a given number of characters. However, you add to add the null byte yourself. This should work (not tested):

```
char* insouts[256][3];
for(x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
    fscanf(file, "input %2c;", insouts[x]);
    insouts[x][2] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried that but when I try to print it out it seems I'm just getting random letters.

     printf("%c",insouts[x][0]);
     printf("%c",insouts[x][1]);
     printf("%c",insouts[x][2]);

Comment: Hm, take a look at my edit and see if that works :) By the way, use printf("%s\n", insouts[x]); to print.

Comment: No, still didn't work. Just random letters still. In the file its:

    input A0;
    input A1;
    input A2;
    input A3;
    input B0;
    input B1;
    input B2;
    input B3;
   output GT;
   output LT;
So if I'm following you right it should be printing out a list of the inputs right?

Comment: Note that it should be `char insouts[256][3];` (plain characters, not pointers).

Comment: Nope, :(. There are less random characters but still just random characters. Should there be anything between where I have file=fopen(); and where I have the code you gave me?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use fscanf why don't you use "getdelim" with ';' as the delimiter. 
According to the man page

" getdelim()  works  like getline(), except that a line delimiter other than newline can be specified as the delimiter argument.  As with getline(), a delimiter character is not added if one was not present in the input before end of file was reached."

So you can do something like (untested and uncompiled code)

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t n, read;
int alloc = 100;
int lc = 0;
char ** buff = calloc(alloc, sizeof(char *)); // since you don't know the file size have 100 buffer and realloc if you need more
FILE *fp = fopen("FILE TO BE READ ", "r");
int deli = (int)';';
while ((read = getline(&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {
   printf("%s", line); // This should have "input A0;" 
   // you can use either sscanf or strtok here and get A0 out 
   char *out = null ;
   sscanf(line, "input %s;", &out);
   if (lc > alloc) {
      alloc = alloc + 50;
      buff = (char **) realloc(buff, sizeof(char *) * alloc);
   }
   buff[lc++] = out
}

int i = 0 ; 
for (i = 0 ; i < lc; i++)
   printf ("%s\n", buff[i]);
```

Comment: I'm sure that works and thank you for the help but I don't particularly understand some of that. I know we haven't gotten to alloc in the class because he said we would be starting that soon.